# How can I write a signature on C# for a wrapped C++ method having double indirection on its arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, interop, dllimport

I'm writing a wrapper for a dll. The dll has a method whose signature resembles the following:

```
unsigned long aMethod(char **firstParameter, char **secondParameter))
```

aMethod returns string pointers to all parameters.

I've searching at google for a tutorial to give me insight on how to write the signature on C# so the framework can do the marshalling process.

How can it be written?
Do you know about any tutorial, book or documentation on this subject?

Comment: Would you essentially like to call this method from managed code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I write a signature on C# for a wrapped C++ method having a pointer to a function it its arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410382/how-can-i-write-a-signature-on-c-for-a-wrapped-c-method-having-a-pointer-to-a)

Comment: A `char*` isn't a pointer to a function. I also don't see any double indirection...

Comment: @dtb sorry... I´ve now corrected the question...

Comment: Well, what do you know about the method parameters that the marshaller might be interested in? For example, do you know that the intention of the parameters are "these are both addresses of variables that contain a null-terminated string implemented as a pointer to char", or what?

Comment: Could you explain what the meaning of those parameters is? `char**` can have many meanings. Are they zero terminated strings passed by reference, or something else?

Comment: But do those parameters mean? `char` is used both for 8-bit binary data and character data. Are those arrays of arrays, pointers to an array, or just pointers to a pointer to a `char`?

Comment: @Eric the intention is to point to standard C strings

Comment: You still haven specified important issues like ownership, length of the strings/size of buffers, who allocates them, who deallocates them,...

Comment: Do you want to transfer strings from C# to C (In), from C to C# (Out) or both (In/Out)? Who is allocating the memory? And who is responsible for freeing it?

Comment: @Juan: Well sure, but like CodeInChaos says, that's just the beginning of what you have to know to marshal it correctly. Do you intend to *write a new string pointer* into that location? Do you intend to modify the existing string buffer? Are the two pointers possibly aliases for each other?

Comment: @Eric hmm the signature comes from an obscure API... The function returns on those parameters pointers to strings. I´m reading that info from a device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer:

The signature has to be like this:

```
[DllImport(aDll.dll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
    CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static unsafe extern ulong aMethod(ref IntPtr firstParameter, 
    ref IntPtr secondParameter);
```

Parameters should be declared as here:

```
IntPtr firstParameter = new IntPtr();
IntPtr secondParameter = new IntPtr();
```

And invocation is done as:

```
aMethod(ref firstParameter, ref secondParameter);
```

Marshalling and unmarshalling related to the strings as here:

```
Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(firstParameter)
Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(secondParameter)
```

Obviously, this marshalling has been selected based on dll´s API conventions.

I´m not sure after all, but all the problems had they source in the `Charset` and `CallingConvention` options...

Answer (score 0):

Not really answering you question but one tool that can help you if you have a lot of methods in a .dll that you want to call from C# is swig http://www.swig.org . It let's you generate a wrapper around the .dll from a interface file. One way to learn how to do it would be to study how swig does it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just write it as

```
ulong aMethod(out IntPtr firstParameter, out IntPtr secondParameter);
```

To use it:

```
IntPtr p1;
IntPtr p2;

aMethod(out p1, out p2);

string p1Str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(p1);
string p2Str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(p2);
```

I'm assuming, of course, that you don't want to operate on the actual memory returned by that method. If you want to operate on the actual bytes, you can call `Marshal.ReadByte`, passing it the pointer that you received.

Note that if the called method is allocating memory for those strings before passing them to you, you have a memory leak unless you can call something in that API to free the memory.

Also note that if you're operating directly on the bytes, there's no guarantee that something else in the API won't pull the rug out from under you.

Comment: Thanks! you illuminated me on using the marshalling and unmarshalling of my pointers